# document.getElementById fails on <div> in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following script to set a `height` on a `div` containing a Google Map control:

```
<script>
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
    //alert("Height:" + height)
    document.getElementById('divMap').setAttribute("style", "width:" + height);
</script>
```

Further down, the `div` is defined:

```
    <div id="divMap" class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 800px; height:100%">
        <map:GoogleMap ID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
        </map:GoogleMap>

        <map:GoogleMarkers ID="GoogleMarkers1" TargetControlID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" OnClick="GoogleMarkers1_Click" />
    </div>
```

The script works wonderfully on load. I get the `height` of the browser window.

However, `getElementById()` always fails.

It's like the `div` doesn't exist when the script runs. If I choose to debug the page, nothing more than the `<script>` tags are shown.

[image: debuging script]

I'm missing something, but what?

Or is there another way to set the `height` of a `div` in asp.net?

Comment: Probably you need to put your scripts inside `(function() {/*your script*/})`. And put your scripts at the end of the `body`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Well, I didn't used jQuery, but the idea to put your scripts inside self execution function like in above comment, is probably false idea, but putting scripts at the bottom of body should do the trick.

Comment: Yes I see @SeM, but why not using the built-in events instead like `DOMContentLoaded` event so we don't have to move the code anywhere (check my answer bellow)

Comment: The key lies here: "***Further down**, the `div` is defined*" - you can't find `divMap` because it doesn't exist yet

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I didn't realise that `<scripts>` where executed during loading this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you are trying to access the div before it is in the DOM. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divMap" class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 800px; height:100%">
<map:GoogleMap ID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%">
</map:GoogleMap>
<map:GoogleMarkers ID="GoogleMarkers1" TargetControlID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" OnClick="GoogleMarkers1_Click" />
</div>

<script>
(function() {
   /var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
    //alert("Height:" + height)
    document.getElementById('divMap').setAttribute("style", "width:" + height);

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I believe this is because you load the `script` tag first before loading the body. When the `script` load first it will look for the element which does not exist yet in the `body`. Therefore it cannot find the element. You need to put the `script` at the bottom.

Like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="divMap">
    ...
  </div>
  <script>
     ...
  </script>
</body>
```

You need to let the element load first. So the element will exist in the body.

Comment: This just another way of do it

Comment: According to the error message, `document.getElementById('divMap')` is *`undefined` or `null`*, so it won't help

Comment: Could you provide the full code? So we can debug it easier.

Comment: I think I got it why. Its because you load the script First. When the scripts load first the dom doesn't exist yet. So you need to put your script at the bottom. Let the element load first.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `divMap` is not found `null` or `undefined` what means you script code can't be found in the DOM what means, in other words, the script tries to get the element when it's not loaded yet.

So to make sure all the DOM elements are loaded before the script runs you could add you code inside the ready function like :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
     //Your code here
});
```

**NOTE:** If you have the control over the page structure you could separate the JS from the HTML in the body, since mixing them isn't a good practise.